# What does “upstage card” mean in “If I play bridge, I will refer to playing my chosen suit as using an “upstage card.”?

Tags: meaning

There was the following paragraph in an article written by Joel Stein under the title “How Trump went mainstream (and you can too)” in Time magazine (May 26).

> “We should also be aware of our complicity in normalizing the
>   dangerous. So until this election is over, I vow not to invite Donald
>   Trump to my house. I will also not pour the bottle of Trump sparking
>   wine I own, even in a mimosa where no one would know. If I play
>   bridge, I will refer to playing my chosen suit as using an “**upstage
>   card.”**

I’m curious to know what the “upstage card” mean. Does it mean a “strategic” card promising you to win the game, or the card that upstage you in terms of status, position, wealth, and whatever?

Why is it put in quotes? Is it a special usage of the word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bridge, the winner of a trick leads the card to start the next trick, i.e., chooses the first card to play for that trick.  If that person is the winner of the bidding, then he may have chosen a suit (one of clubs, hears, diamonds, or spades) that will outrank the others for the duration of the hand.  This suit it called *trump*, and by its nature the lowest trump (the deuce) ranks higher than highest card (an ace) of any other suit.  In playing the hand, you could say, metaphorically speaking, that a low trump "upstages" the cards of the other suits, even those with a higher face value.

The writer is saying that he will use the word *upstage* so he doesn't have to say the word *trump*, which is spelled and pronounce like the name Trump.

So an "upstage card" is a card that ranks higher than others for the duration of the hand.  It's in quotes because it really isn't a proper bridge term, but one invented for the moment.

Comment: The presidential candidate's name provides a whole world of opportunity for sub-editors and general punsters. Should you trump a Trump? Is a deuce of trumps a Drumpf? If a trump is played, should second player play low?